# I don't know where to start...htaccess file and probably Apache?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, internal-server-error

I have no idea what any of this stuff means. I just know that GoDaddy tech support said it's a problem with .htaccess, WordPress and Apache.

Briefly, when I remove the .htaccess file from the root directory, my blog's pages and category links result in an Internal Server Error, while the custom 404 pages in my other site's directories work fine.

And vice versa.  When I put a blank .htaccess file on the root directory, my blog works and my other directory sites get an Internal Server Error instead of the custom 404.

I did a screencast video to actually explain and show the problem I'm having and hopefully someone can figure it out and point me in the right direction.

As far as writing code - I can copy/paste what I'm given but I'm not a programmer.  This is all foreign to me and it's really very frustrating.

Here is the video on YouTube that will better explain what is happening, in case I haven't explained it correctly.

http://youtu.be/8FL1ihplQws

Thank you!

Karen

Comment: the htaccess is required to ensure the user is able to navigate properly on the site.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-htaccess - ensure this stuff is inside the httaccess so the site can work

Answer (score 2):

Put the original .htaccess back in the root folder

Create a new .htaccess file containing the following

RewriteEngine Off

Place this in the subfolders such as the-bookmarks-store

My hunch is that the addon domains are reading the .htaccess but the rewrite rules are invalid for that website. My suggested cure turns off the rewrite for the addon domains

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use default permalink structure like `?p=123` ? 
Try changing back and forth and see if links work with default setting!